# Controversy surrounding the Fiscal Theory of the Price Level (FTPL)

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, fiscal-policy

I recently started reading a draft of John Cochrane's book on the Fiscal Theory of the Price Level. In the preface he states that the "[...] theoretical controversies are over." However, given that he is clearly a proponent of the theory, I would be interested in understanding the state of the discussion, i.e. whether the theory is widely accepted by now? Are there good papers summarizing the discussion surrounding the FTPL?